# Dockerfile & Docker Compose with Java Spring Boot, Gradle and PostgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

Hi fellow StackOverflow users! I am writing this question here because I find the lack of resources a bit scary, when it comes to Spring Boot Java applications with Docker.
My goal is to create a fully featured warehouse management system as an example of good practices with Spring Boot, and as a learning experience for myself and others in many concepts of the framework.

I am trying to create a Dockerfile so that my application can be run as a Docker image in a container, alongside a PostgreSQL database.

The application can be found [here on GitHub](https://github.com/averageflow/spring-warehouse).

The `Dockerfile` of the application is :

```
FROM gradle:jdk17-alpine
RUN mkdir /home/gradle/buildWorkspace
COPY . /home/gradle/buildWorkspace

WORKDIR /home/gradle/buildWorkspace
RUN ls /home/gradle/buildWorkspace
RUN gradle build --no-daemon
RUN ls /home/gradle/buildWorkspace/app/build/distributions/
RUN tar -xvf /home/gradle/buildWorkspace/app/build/distributions/app.tar
EXPOSE 8080
```

and `docker-compose.yaml`

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  db:
    container_name: "PostgresWarehouseDB"
    image: "postgres:14.0-alpine"
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: warehouse_user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: warehouse_user_password
      POSTGRES_DB: warehouse_db
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - "./storage/migrations:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/"
  app:
    container_name: "SpringWarehouse"
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: .
    links:
      - "db:database"
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    command: /home/gradle/buildWorkspace/app/build/distributions/app/bin/app
```

the `application.properties`:

```
spring.main.banner-mode=off
logging.level.org.springframework=ERROR

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true

spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.datasource.platform=postgres
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/warehouse_db
spring.datasource.username=warehouse_user
spring.datasource.password=warehouse_user_password


# Log JPA queries
# Comment this in production
# spring.jpa.show-sql=true

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

I am using Java 17, Gradle 7 and latest dependencies.

I have gotten as far as managing to build the application with Gradle and to start it up with `docker-compose up` alongside PostgreSQL (with an initial migration).

My issue is that somehow it seems to be unreachable via network, so my application cannot access the database, and thus does not function correctly.

I get the following trace:

```
PostgresWarehouseDB | PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.
PostgresWarehouseDB | 
PostgresWarehouseDB | 2021-12-08 14:54:19.850 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 14.0 on x86_64-pc-linux-musl, compiled by gcc (Alpine 10.3.1_git20210424) 10.3.1 20210424, 64-bit
PostgresWarehouseDB | 2021-12-08 14:54:19.850 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
PostgresWarehouseDB | 2021-12-08 14:54:19.851 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
PostgresWarehouseDB | 2021-12-08 14:54:19.861 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
PostgresWarehouseDB | 2021-12-08 14:54:19.872 UTC [52] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2021-12-08 14:54:19 UTC
PostgresWarehouseDB | 2021-12-08 14:54:19.880 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
SpringWarehouse | 14:54:21.580 [Thread-0] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader - Created RestartClassLoader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader@72f7771e
SpringWarehouse | 2021-12-08 14:54:22.468  INFO 1 --- [  restartedMain] n.a.s.SpringWarehouseApplication         : Starting SpringWarehouseApplication using Java 17.0.1 on 64eae67a1990 with PID 1 (/home/gradle/buildWorkspace/app/build/distributions/app/lib/app.jar started by root in /home/gradle/buildWorkspace)
SpringWarehouse | 2021-12-08 14:54:22.474  INFO 1 --- [  restartedMain] n.a.s.SpringWarehouseApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
SpringWarehouse | 2021-12-08 14:54:25.961  INFO 1 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
SpringWarehouse | 2021-12-08 14:54:25.962  INFO 1 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.55]
SpringWarehouse | 2021-12-08 14:54:26.152  INFO 1 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
SpringWarehouse | 2021-12-08 14:54:26.559  INFO 1 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
SpringWarehouse | 2021-12-08 14:54:26.663  INFO 1 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.1.Final
SpringWarehouse | 2021-12-08 14:54:26.958  INFO 1 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
SpringWarehouse | 2021-12-08 14:54:27.145  INFO 1 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
SpringWarehouse | 2021-12-08 14:54:28.270 ERROR 1 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
SpringWarehouse | 
SpringWarehouse | org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
SpringWarehouse |       at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:301) ~[postgresql-42.3.1.jar:42.3.1]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:51) ~[postgresql-42.3.1.jar:42.3.1]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:225) ~[postgresql-42.3.1.jar:42.3.1]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:466) ~[postgresql-42.3.1.jar:42.3.1]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:265) ~[postgresql-42.3.1.jar:42.3.1]
SpringWarehouse |       at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
SpringWarehouse |       at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
SpringWarehouse |       at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
SpringWarehouse |       at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
SpringWarehouse |       at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
SpringWarehouse |       at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
SpringWarehouse |       at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:181) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:178) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:175) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:127) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1460) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1494) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1290) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
SpringWarehouse |       at nl.averageflow.springwarehouse.SpringWarehouseApplication.main(SpringWarehouseApplication.java:10) ~[app.jar:na]
SpringWarehouse |       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
SpringWarehouse |       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
SpringWarehouse |       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
SpringWarehouse |       at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
SpringWarehouse | Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
SpringWarehouse |       at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
SpringWarehouse |       at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672) ~[na:na]
SpringWarehouse |       at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:542) ~[na:na]
SpringWarehouse |       at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:597) ~[na:na]
SpringWarehouse |       at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327) ~[na:na]
SpringWarehouse |       at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633) ~[na:na]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.createSocket(PGStream.java:238) ~[postgresql-42.3.1.jar:42.3.1]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:98) ~[postgresql-42.3.1.jar:42.3.1]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:100) ~[postgresql-42.3.1.jar:42.3.1]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:215) ~[postgresql-42.3.1.jar:42.3.1]
SpringWarehouse |       ... 55 common frames omitted
SpringWarehouse | 
SpringWarehouse | 2021-12-08 14:54:28.275  WARN 1 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata
SpringWarehouse | 
SpringWarehouse | org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
SpringWarehouse |       at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:301) ~[postgresql-42.3.1.jar:42.3.1]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:51) ~[postgresql-42.3.1.jar:42.3.1]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:225) ~[postgresql-42.3.1.jar:42.3.1]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:466) ~[postgresql-42.3.1.jar:42.3.1]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:265) ~[postgresql-42.3.1.jar:42.3.1]
SpringWarehouse |       at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
SpringWarehouse |       at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
SpringWarehouse |       at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
SpringWarehouse |       at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
SpringWarehouse |       at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
SpringWarehouse |       at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
SpringWarehouse |       at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:181) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:178) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:175) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:127) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1460) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1494) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1290) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
SpringWarehouse |       at nl.averageflow.springwarehouse.SpringWarehouseApplication.main(SpringWarehouseApplication.java:10) ~[app.jar:na]
SpringWarehouse |       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
SpringWarehouse |       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
SpringWarehouse |       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
SpringWarehouse |       at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
SpringWarehouse | Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
SpringWarehouse |       at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
SpringWarehouse |       at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672) ~[na:na]
SpringWarehouse |       at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:542) ~[na:na]
SpringWarehouse |       at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:597) ~[na:na]
SpringWarehouse |       at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327) ~[na:na]
SpringWarehouse |       at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633) ~[na:na]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.createSocket(PGStream.java:238) ~[postgresql-42.3.1.jar:42.3.1]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:98) ~[postgresql-42.3.1.jar:42.3.1]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:100) ~[postgresql-42.3.1.jar:42.3.1]
SpringWarehouse |       at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:215) ~[postgresql-42.3.1.jar:42.3.1]
SpringWarehouse |       ... 55 common frames omitted
SpringWarehouse | 
SpringWarehouse | 2021-12-08 14:54:28.296  INFO 1 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
SpringWarehouse | 2021-12-08 14:54:29.605  INFO 1 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
SpringWarehouse | 2021-12-08 14:54:32.061  INFO 1 --- [  restartedMain] n.a.s.SpringWarehouseApplication         : Started SpringWarehouseApplication in 10.457 seconds (JVM running for 11.504)
```

I have had success before with similar `docker-compose` files and I do not understand what I am missing here. I will certainly share my findings here and in my personal blog, to help future developers in the same situation.

Any help is kindly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try update your `application.properties`: spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://**db**:5432/warehouse_db

Comment: It's not clear for me. Does host name depend simply on service name which we set in docker-compose or other property?

Comment: `...host name depend simply on service name` - see ["...the following happens:"](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/). **NOTE:** an exception is if you use `container_name` to override.